# Pandas: How to check if the column contains value 0 then sort the selected rows data according to some rule?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting

I have a data frame

```
Testcase   Processing_time   Pass   Fail   avg_failure_rate   Ranking_value
   t1         1.102088        8    26        76.47           69.38
   t2         1.718864        19    3        13.63           7.93
   t3         25              22    0         0               0
   t4         15              22    0         0               0
```

I want to keep the first two test cases as it is from the above data frame, but I want to sort the rest of the test cases based on the shortest processing time column.

Desired output:

```
TestCase   Processing_time  Pass  Fail  avg_failure_rate  Ranking_value
   t1         1.102088        8    26        76.47           69.38
   t2         1.718864        19    3        13.63           7.93
   t4         15              22    0         0               0
   t3         25              22    0         0               0
```

If the test cases have a ranking value equal to 0, they should be sorted based on the shortest processing time rule.
Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: The dataframes are equal

Comment: now they are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter with rank value 0 with [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and sort by [`.sort_values()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). Then append back to the other part with rank value not equal 0 by [`.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), as follows:

```
df.loc[df['Ranking_value'] != 0].append(df.loc[df['Ranking_value'] == 0].sort_values('Processing_time'))
```

**Result:**

```
  Testcase  Processing_time  Pass  Fail  avg_failure_rate  Ranking_value
0       t1         1.102088     8    26             76.47          69.38
1       t2         1.718864    19     3             13.63           7.93
3       t4        15.000000    22     0              0.00           0.00
2       t3        25.000000    22     0              0.00           0.00
```

Comment: Thank you it worked

Answer (score 2):

Do it with two steps, split the dataframe then `concat` back

```
idx = df.index[df.Ranking_value==0]
out = pd.concat([df.drop(idx),df[idx].sort_values('Processing_time')])
Out[120]: 
  Testcase  Processing_time  Pass  Fail  avg_failure_rate  Ranking_value
0       t1         1.102088     8    26             76.47          69.38
1       t2         1.718864    19     3             13.63           7.93
3       t4        15.000000    22     0              0.00           0.00
2       t3        25.000000    22     0              0.00           0.00
```

Comment: This is just an example which I have given. The real-time data consist of 1000 test cases. Which top 100 have ranking value but the rest of the 900 test cases have a ranking value equal to zero. Is the solution which you provided will work for this situation?

Comment: @PforPython yes , change the 2 to 100 will work for u, and also check the update

Answer (score 0):

Try maskning.

```
mask = df.loc[:,“Ranking_value”] == 0. 

df.loc[mask,:].sort_values(“Processing_time”,inplace=True)
```

Comment: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match). -------> getting this error

Comment: What about now?